# How does one dynamically hide images in Go using GOTK3?

Tags: go, gtk

I'm using Go and GOTK, and I have a UI widget which contains a few child widgets.  In the parent widget, I'd like to dynamically show and hide images within it, and when images are hidden, I don't want the hidden images to take up any space on the screen.

I've tried doing this:

```
image, _ := gtk.ImageNewFromFile(...)
myWidget.Add(image)

...and then later
image.Hide()
```

...however this didn't have any affect on the image and it remained visible.  I also tried: `myWidget.Remove(image)` but this didn't hide the image either.

The only thing I've found that's close, is to define a CSS class:

```
.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

...and then later, when I want to hide the image, do:

```
    context, _ := image.GetStyleContext()
    context.AddClass("hidden")
```

This hides the image, but the screen real estate occupied by the image is still reserved.

As an example of what I'd like to do, suppose I have several images and some labels in my widget, but only want to display one image at a time - an example of this might be a "play/stop" image, and only display the play image while stopped, and only display the stop image while playing (and each are displayed in the same location)

I also tried defining a CSS class which sets the display to none:

```
.display-none {
    display: none
}
```

...but I get an error with this, that 'display' is not a valid property name.

Is it possible to dynamically show & hide images?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `image.set_visible(False)`.